# Wolfram cloud and typing short cut

Tags: formatting, wolfram-cloud

I subscribed Wolfram Cloud just a few days ago, and now I trying to get used to it.

I’m using iPad pro(gen 2) with the smart keyboard for it, and access on the Cloud via Wolfram cloud app.

But I'm struggling with typing subscription, power, fraction and Greek letters etc as on desktop environment.

I cannot use, for example, “ctrl(cmd maybe on Mac?) + _” to write subscript, and “ctrl + /” to convert a input into fractional form.

Also the short cut for escape key on iPad(which is “control + [”) does not work on the app, and others seem not to be alternatives, too.

May I ask anyone to confirm whether those issue could be resolved on (iPad+cloud app) environment?
Should I wait for next update for it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Also an iPad user. I have the same question. Typing is also really bugged. Sometimes, typing does not work at all. For some reason, pressing a key on the top keyboard will then allow typing on the (bottom) normal keyboard to work again; it's really bizarre.

Comment: It seems that Ctrl + ‘=‘ does work, so Ctrl is the correct key. I would worry about typing though, as you cannot edit an evaluated input using a keyboard (you by pressing a key first on top on screen keyboard); it’s so buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Type your regular expressions using _ for subscripts and ^ for superscripts. Then move to the very right and hover the mouse pointer over the cell bracket. A tiny gear icon should appear. Click on it to pop up a context menu. In that menu, go to "Convert to" and select "TraditionalForm." The subscripts and superscripts should now render in the right positions.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer! But, unfortunately(maybe fortunate for me) I bought new laptop, so that I don't need to use Wolfram cloud no more. I just bought one more license of Mathematia for the laptop. Thank you again!

Comment: This worked terribly for me. I recommend saving your work before trying this